# dpl unable to push to unqualified destination: master

Tags: git, azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, travis-ci

I am using travis's `dpl` cmd to push to azure website:

```
dpl --provider=AzureWebApps --username=$AZURE_WA_USERNAME --password=$AZURE_WA_PASSWORD --site=xxx --verbose
```

I got this error:

```
 error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
 The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
 begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: Did you set up a deployment source for you web app? It seams that the master branch is not in the remote side any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by:

```
git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

Because the repo is empty by default...